# Field values sometimes do not show up in grid view or node view for non admin users

Tags: 7, views, nodes, users

I have a view that is sorted by the number of times a user visits a node and clicks the play button (the play button is a menu item of the node).  Every time the play button has pressed the value of an integer field inside the node is incremented and this value is used to sort my view.  I also display the value "Times Played" both in the view and the node.  When I look at the view as admin everything looks good, like this:

[image]

But when I look at the view as a normal user the view is still sorted correctly but some of the nodes don't show the value for "Times Played", here is that screenshot:
[image]

Also, when I view the actual node page as an admin I see always see the correct value for "Times Played" but when I visited it as a normal user I get the same behavior I see in the view.  Any idea what could be going on here?  Is this some strange permissions issue?

Comment: what happens when you add another simple text field to the content-type? Does that show up in all the instances in both the view and node page?

Comment: Yes if I add a static integer field that is only set once (when the node is created). It shows up in both the view and the node page, for both standard and admin users.

Comment: are all the nodes of the same type? or is the issue with a specific node type?

Comment: This is really strange issue indeed. Just guessing here but could it be that clicking the play button as a particular user/role prevents the count down to show up because of that?

Comment: @MohammedShameem all of the nodes that exhibit this problem are of the same type.

Comment: @undersound I'm not sure most of the user's clicking the button are not admin users.

Comment: Do you use any field permissions modules? In your view what is listed under Show -> Format (fields or content?) What happens when you switch those?

Comment: Field permissions module was installed but when I disable it, the problem still happens.  It was in show -> form fields, when I switch to content it no longer shows many of my fields (including "Times Played").

Comment: sorry but I have no idea then, have to see some code / experiment with different settings

Comment: Do you have per-field permissions set up? Do authenticated ("normal") users have access to view the relevant nodes?

Comment: @Mike2012 What is the markup when the field is displayed and when it's empty? Did you check Drupal log (like dblog)?

Comment: @Mike2012, what if you run the query with Advanced>Other>Query Settings, try checking Disable SQL rewriting

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to embed view in your template file?   `$embed = views_embed_view('name_of_view','display_id');` . You need also to check permissions

Answer (score 0):

In the query options of the view disable SQL rewriting and see what happens. If your fields appear again for all the users then you have some kind of restriction at field level.